# Navigation Bar does not show

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I try to figure this all the morning. Got no idea why my view does not have the navigation button... to back up in the main view ?

Can anyone explain it to me ?

```
    import UIKit
    class LiveStockList: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "back!", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backToViewController))
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
        }


        func backToViewController(_ : Any) {
            let viewController = ViewController()
            let navController = UINavigationController (rootViewController: viewController)
            present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

}
```

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: Nop. I try to do this programmatically.

Comment: please show you AppDelegate.swift file code

Comment: https://pastebin.com/VDeVuXgP

Comment: You are saying that initially your button is not added in the navigation bar? please show the screenshot if you can

Comment: The navigation bar is missing. I just got a white screen. If i change the bg color to green is green. So the view is loading... but not that navbar.

Comment: Ok have you removed the storyboard from the project?

Comment: When you're calling your ViewController, is it embedded in a Navigation Controller? If the `ParentViewController` is  a `NavigationController`, just push this `LiveStockList`. If it's not, then before you present the `LiveStockList` you need to embed the `LiveStockList` as `rootViewController` of the `NavigationController`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that are misleading us here.

The `ViewController` that you want to go back to is the one that presented the current `ListStockList ViewController`?

If it is, don't call the `present(_:)` method, but instead call the `dismiss(_:completion)` method.

If you cannot see the `UINavigationBar` you have to check a few things.

If the `ViewController (parent)` is a `NavigationController`, just call `push(:_ViewController)` method and you should be able to see the navBar.

If the parent `ViewController` is not embedded in a `NavigationController` then when you present the `LiveStockList` you need to embed it in a `NavigationController` before presenting it.

Something like this:

```
let liveStockList = LiveStockList()
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: liveStockList)
present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then in your `LiveStockList` you should be able to see the `navigationBar` as expected.

Otherwise you might have done something different and we might need additional info.

Answer (score 0):

According to your Question "Got no idea why my view does not have the navigation button... to back up in the main view".

You said navigation button to back up in the main view is missing, it is because you are presenting a new navigation controller.

You just need to push view controller from existing Navigation Controller.

i have example of code:

`let vc = UIViewController()
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`

it will work if your existing View Controller is embed in UINavigationController.

still, if you want to present a controller then you should add a UIBarButtonItem to your navigation controller and on action of that UIBarButtonItem you should "DISMISS" the View Controller because previously you "PRESENT" View Controller.

Let me know if any query, Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking in the wrong place. In the ViewController, I have a button that launches the LiveStockList Controller.
It was doing its job just launching the controller and made the transition.

Code:

```
 func meniu1ButtonPressed () {

    let liveStockList = LiveStockList()
    present(liveStockList, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

After I added a new line to that function, it looks like this:

```
func meniu1ButtonPressed () {

    let liveStockList = LiveStockList()
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: liveStockList)
    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

...and it is now working. It is showing me the back button and loading the ViewController again.